# Dual boot Windows 7 + Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, system-installation, gparted, boot-partition

I want to dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10, but when I choose installation type it says:

```
There is no recognized operating systems on my computer.
```

So basically my options are either `erase disc and install Ubuntu` or `Something else`. I need to select `something else`.

Before that, do I need to resize some partitions in `gparted` ? I wasn't able to get a image so they were as follows:

```
/dev/sda3 43.72GiB       Unallocated 67.84GiB
Partition `/dev/sda1     Filesystem fat32  Mount point -  size 100.00MiB Used 21.76MiB Unused: 78.24 MiB  Flags boot

/dev/sda2!  Filesystem unknown Mount point - Size 128.00MiB  Used -  Unused - Flags msftres
/dev/sda3   Filesystem ntfs    Mount point /media/ubuntu/D0489CBE489CA4AE  Size 43.72GiB  Used 28.63GiB  Unused 15.o9 GiB  Flags  msftdata

Unallocated  Filesystem Unallocated Mount point -  Size 67.84GiB  Used - Unused - Flags
```

Now I would like to know how should I resize these partitions in gparted? After that when choosing `Something else` in **Installation Type** what partitions should I create (maybe `swap`, `ext4 journalizing file system`?) And moreover: 'How can I get a working bootloader with Windows and Ubuntu'. I don`t want to use my repair CD-disc [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Thanks

Comment: It automatically includes windows entry in Ubuntu grub boot loader you don`t need to use boot-repair.

Comment: [Click Me!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeSaVzyPY8k)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by resizing the partitions in windows (I have win 8).

You need to resize if you don't have free space. Or you can format some partition - but that's what you dont't want.

You have to create partitions:

- swap,
- filesystem (ext4 recommended - but if you want to access it from windows you need 3rd party driver),
- BIOS reserved space (around 2MB).

Answer (score 0):

Although it's better to choose "something else", you should have the second option available instead of "There is no recognized operating systems on my computer." Check it out.
As for your question about partition, you can use windows 7's own resize utility, but since you have 60Gb unallocated space you can simply use that to install your Ubuntu. I think it depend on your ram to decide if you should make a 1-2G /swap, and besides that you should have a /, a /boot, and optionally a /Home.

Comment: Ok thx. I should use the unallocated space 67gt  to create ext4 filesystem and mount point that as /? (size about 45gt). Then I need to create /swap with size about 2000MB? I think 300MB is enough for /boot? What is /Home for? Should bootloader be in dev/sda/SATA KINGSTON(first option?)

Comment: Just follow this tutorial: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/ I just installed it with no problem. For your system I agree with your thoughts.  Bootloader should be in /boot, NOT first default option, otherwise you have Grub instead of Windows bootloader(but that's fine, for me I like to use windows's bootloader and add Grub as a boot option as in that tutorial, so in case linux corrupted your windows is fine). Good Luck!

Comment: Btw: /Home mounted seperately is for the purpose of system/data seperation, so if you need to reinstall your system you don't have to format /Home partition, which saves all your personal settings and data by default.